# Iterating over the dictionary elements and adding them into a List

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

As i am iterating over the dictionary elements and adding them into a List. Here i need to select "item" on basis of key elements and store it into List.

```
  {"0":["1234","2222","4321","211000","90024","12","2121","322223","2332","3232"],"1":["0856","6040222","175002","23572","","","","","",""]}

    List<string> strlist;
    strlist = new List<string>();

    var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);

    foreach (var item in jr)
    {
      // Need to add item on basis of Key
      // Can we include any where clause
       strlist.AddRange(item.Value);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what `Need to add item on basis of Key` means correctly then this should work for you:

```
List<string> strlist = new List<string>();
var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);

foreach (var item in jr)
{
  if(item.Key == "someKey")
  {
      strlist.AddRange(item.Value);
  }
}
```

or if you have multiple keys you wants to match on:

```
List<string> strlist = new List<string>();
var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);
List<string> targetKeys = new List<string>{"someKey", "anotherKey", "oneAwesomeKey"};

foreach (var item in jr)
{
  if(targetKeys.Contains(item.Key))
  {
      strlist.AddRange(item.Value);
  }
}
```

The first example here shows adding a dictionary value only if the key is equal to a defined string (`someKey` in this example). The second example shows adding a dictionary value if the dictionary key is contained in a defined list of strings.

You can also use linq to achieve this as follows:

```
var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);

var strlist= jr.Where(x => x.Key == "someKey").SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

likewise to match on multiple keys:

```
var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);
List<string> targetKeys = new List<string>{"someKey", "anotherKey", "oneAwesomeKey"};

var strlist= jr.Where(x => targetKeys.Contains(x.Key)).SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i need, List object i.e. "strlist" populate using "where clause" where we can select item values on basis of KEY. For eg

strlist.AddRange(jr.SelectMany(a => a.Value)); // Here would to include where clause.

Comment: are you saying you want to use linq?

Comment: Actually List is going to get populated on basis of Where condition,

Comment: `.Where` is a function from `System.Linq` . Please check the updated answer

Comment: @dipak is the updated answer what your going for? If not, please try to elaborate a little more clearly on what you're looking for as I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding exactly what you're looking for and I'd love to help